# How to configure an OpenAM SAML token to include the SSO Token?

Tags: saml, openam

I'm using OpenAM as a service provider to provide an encrypted SAML token to a Salesforce canvas app.

Ideally I would like this SAML token to contain the OpenAM SSO token to enable the canvas app to refresh the SAML token. How do I add this to the SAML token?

Answer (score 1):

There is no out of the box solution for this, I think you'll need to write a custom Attribute Mapper:
http://docs.forgerock.org/en/openam/12.0.0/apidocs/com/sun/identity/saml2/plugins/IDPAttributeMapper.html